# How the results follows from the reasoning

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $gcd(a, n) = 1 \implies \exists h, k \in Z$ such that $ka + hn = 1$.
>   Then $ka = 1 \pmod n$ so $k$ is the inverse of $a$ mod $n$.

In the above reasoning, I don't get according to what theorem it's obtained that $ka + hn = 1$ and $ka = 1 \pmod n$. Please shed some light on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

Comment: Thank you. What about the other part where it's obtained that $ka=1$?

Comment: It's not $ka=1$, it's $ka=1\pmod n$. When we write $x=y\pmod n$, we mean $y-x$ is a multiple of $n$. Can you see why that's true in your situation?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Oops, yes I can see that. Thank you.